# Eclipse - Update WSDL after creating a new operation

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, wsdl

I just implemented a new SOAP webservice with a simple operation in eclipse,generated and deployed the wsdl and implemented a client to check if everything worked.

It worked, but now I want to add some more operations to my WS, and I cant seem to figure out how to update the WSDL in order to reflect the new operations.

Can someone explain how this is done?

Thanks!

This is my interface:

```
public interface IService {


    public int sayHello(String msg);

    public int addCI(int i);

}
```

And this is the Service implementation class:

```
@WebService
public class Service implements IService {

public Service() {}


@WebMethod
public int sayHello(String msg) {
    System.out.println("teste");
    return 200; 
}

@WebMethod
public int addCI(int i) {
    System.out.println("new element");
    return 200;
}

}
```

The operation sayHello is present in the wsdl, while addCI is not.
There doesnt seem to be a way in Eclipse to regenerate WSDL from source, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you took the "Java First" approach and that your WSDL is being auto generated. If this is the case, then any non-static/final method in your Service Implementation Bean(SIB) will be exposed in the WSDL as long as it follows the rules below:

- public methods with @WebMethod with the exclude element set to false.
- public methods with @WebMethod with no exclude element (since false is the default).
- public methods not annotated @WebMethod annotation but their declaring class (might be a parent class) has a @WebService annotation.

Example:

```
@WebService
public class Test {

    @WebMethod
    public void foo(){
        //Operation in WSDL
    }

    public void newOperation(){
        //Also in WSDL
    }

    //Not in WSDL
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    }
}
```